# Apache Beam Python SDK for Windowing with SQL

Tags: python-3.x, apache-flink, apache-beam

The problem is, I want to make a windowing inside SqlTransform as

```
SELECT f_timestamp, line, COUNT(*)
FROM PCOLLECTION
GROUP BY
   line,
   HOP(f_timestamp, INTERVAL '30' MINUTE, INTERVAL '1' HOUR)
```

My `Row` transformation mapping is

```
| "Create beam Row" >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(f_timestamp= float(x["timestamp_date"]), line = unicode(x["line"])))
```

And I have an error on the Java side as

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: 
Cannot apply 'HOP' to arguments of type 'HOP(<DOUBLE>, <INTERVAL MINUTE>, <INTERVAL HOUR>)'. 
Supported form(s): 'HOP(<DATETIME>, <DATETIME_INTERVAL>, <DATETIME_INTERVAL>)'
```

The things I tried:

- Make the `f_timestamp` UNIX timestamp, as a `float`.
- Make the `f_timestamp` string timestamp as a `unicode`.

As I read, Java side uses `java.util.Date` on the timestamp, how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `apache_beam.utils.timestamp.Timestamp` for this.